# Recover files from windows

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, undelete

I recently replaced my operating system windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04 and forgot to backup a few family pictures. And I was wondering if it's possible to retrieve them, and if how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99.9% they are lost. But there is a remote 0.1% chance (If you are extermely lucky) you may salvage something out of it.Give it a try with http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step or http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Answer (score 0):

No, once you replaced your windows with Ubuntu you copied gigabytes of data over your hard disk. This means all the links that would have possibly remained, and possible be used to recover your files, are now lost.